# cakePHP Paginator issue with second model

Tags: cakephp, pagination, paginator

still a novice, but I am fighting with the paginator to limit my view to 10 records [properties] and to sort it on a field in the properties model. What am I doing wrong or miss in my code to get the paginator to control my view???

I have 2 models, Regions and Properties, a region has many properties, for example, my view is /region/view/13  This shows all properties for region 13.

The paginator is displaying the correct amount of properties, set the pages correct and all seems correct, but the paginator is not limiting my view, it just displays all properties by that region in one huge list instead of limit the view to 10 per page.
The sort per sleeps doesn't work either although the url in the browser seems to be ok.

```
/regions/view/13/sort:sleeps/direction:asc
/regions/view/13/sort:sleeps/direction:desc
```

Model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
* Region Model
*
* @property Country $Country
* @property Property $Property
*/
class Region extends AppModel {

/**
* Display field
*
* @var string
*/
public $displayField = 'regionname';


/**
* belongsTo associations
*
* @var array
*/
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Country' => array(
        'className' => 'Country',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

/**
* hasMany associations
*
* @var array
*/
public $hasMany = array(
    'Property' => array(
        'className' => 'Property',
        'foreignKey' => 'region_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);

}
```

Controller:

```
    public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Region->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid region'));
    }
            $this->Region->recursive = 2; // related to associated model data, Region -> Properties -> PropertyImages
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Region.' . $this->Region->primaryKey => $id));
    $total = $this->Region->Property->find('count', array(
                    'conditions' => array('Property.region_id' => $id)
                    ));
            $this->set('total', $total);  // Push to counter the view.
            $this->set('region', $this->Region->find('first', $options)); // Push the properties to the view.
            $this->paginate = array(
                'limit' => 10,    
                'conditions' => array('Property.region_id' => $id),
                );
            $this->Region->Property->virtualFields['sleeps'] = 'Property.sleeps';
            $this->set('regions', $this->paginate('Property'));
}
```

View:

```
<div class="paging">
<?php
echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next   disabled')); ?>
</div>
<br>
<?php
echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
'format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}'))); ?><br>

Total properties: <?php echo $total . "\n"; ?><br>
Sort by: <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('sleeps'); ?>

<?php if (!empty($region['Property'])): ?>
<div class="regionviewfooter"></div>
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach ($region['Property'] as $property): ?>
<!-- We only need 1 image to show up -->
<?php foreach ($property['PropertyImage'] as $key =>$propertyImage): ?>
    <div class="regionview">
        <div class="regionviewleft">
            <?php echo '<span style="font-size:12px;line-height:18px;font-weight:bold;">'; echo $this->Html->link(__($property['description']), array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['id'])); echo '</span>'; ?>
            <div class="regionviewheader">Sleeps&nbsp;<?php echo $property['sleeps']; echo ' :: ' ?>
                    <?php
                    if ($property['minPrice'] == 0) {
                        echo 'Please call for prices';
                    } else {
                        echo 'Prices from ';
                        echo $this->Number->currency($property['minPrice'], 'GBP');
                        if ($property['maxPrice'] == 0) {
                            echo ' PW';
                        } else {
                            echo ' - ';
                            echo $this->Number->currency($property['maxPrice'], 'GBP');
                            echo ' PW';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '<span style="font-size:11px;line-height:18px;font-weight:normal;">'; echo ' :: ';
                    echo $this->Html->link(__('View Property'), array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', $property['id'])); echo '</span>'; ?>
            </div>
                <?php echo ($property['shortDesc']); ?><br>
                <a href="../../enqlist">Add to my Enquiry List</a> :: Property Ref.    (<?php echo strtoupper($property['ref']); ?>)
        </div>
        <div class="regionviewright">
            <!-- display image -->
            <?php echo $this->Html->image(($propertyImage['filename']), array('alt' => ($propertyImage['description']),'width' => '150' ,'height' => '77')); $key ?>
            <?php $key++; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="regionviewfooter"></div>
    <?php if ($key == 1) {
            break; // Stop, we did 1 image.
        }
    ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<br><a href="#top">Top of Page</a><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your paginated results to `$regions`, yet in your view, you're looping through and displaying `$region` (singular), which is a straight-up `find()` above, with recursive 2, which will pull all properties.

So - although there are many other things that need cleaned up with your code, for now, just use `$regions` (plural) instead of `$region` singular in your View.

Comment: Dave,your suggestion throws errors, although being a novice, I think I kept to the recommendations of the MVC naming. Views are plural stored in folder /View/Regions/view.ctp The model singularise. The data needs to be pushed to the regions/view so don't think doing this wrong. I need to set the recursive to 2 to be able to retrieve the image for each property because i am in the region. [Region-Property-PropertyImage] Would you mind please to explain the many other things that needed to be done to cleanup my code? I am eager to learn. Many thanks.

Comment: I never mentioned changing the name of the view or the mode.  The VARIABLES you're using are incorrect.  The variable (in the view) that holds your paginated results is `$regions`.  I don't care if you call it `$pizza`, but that's not what it's set to right now.  Then, you're trying to use `$region` singular to display the paginated results, the that is not the variable that HOLDS the paginated results - it's the one that holds the ENTIRE result set, hence your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I see know what you mean, i will try to get this changed.

Comment: It seems I have huge problem to get both to work together, could someone explain and tell me what to do to get this to work?

Comment: I already have.  If you have other specific questions, feel free to create a question for each of them.

Comment: Ok, I did it, yippie, just wiped all and started again fresh, thanks @Dave